# CSS float right empty space

Tags: html, css

Big problem with float and position ! 
there are multiple divs in page (with  different height). when we use float right there's pretty much odd space left in next row becouse of different height. 
see this link : http://www.webgardha.com/tag/google

I don't prefer to use javascript
Please advice me, how can I remove the space and move the div's up?

Comment: Can you post your code here? With jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you always have two column floated structure then you can try

```
#mainbar article .grid6:nth-child(even) {
    clear: right;
}
```

This will clear float on even .grid6 div

Comment: Thank you Pravin!
This code is in CSS right now and you can see.
It is not working on more result such as this page : 
http://www.webgardha.com/tag/گوگل

Comment: Great! other than this you can google for equal height columns CSS and Javascript solutions Good Luck